# Generating unique list of numbers each time in java

Tags: java, logic

I am trying to generate a list of integers, using JAVA, as below:
01,55,45,23,48,05,45,97

I want to build a logic which will always generate a unique list ie. it should not generate another list having same numbers in same sequence.

One way, I thought of, is to dump the generated list in database and compare the lists which are generated then after. Save the list only if same is not already present in DB table. Is there any another way you guys can think of?

<>
I will describe my question through an Use case:
1. Code generated a list of random numbers. eg. 02,34,45,67,90
2. Second time when code generate list of random numbers, I need to check whether the list generated is : 02,34,45,67,90 ie. the one generated in step 1 or not.

Comment: If you can use `long` numbers, then you can just use the *currentTImeInMilliseconds* as base

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: Storing those integers in the database might be a viable solution depending on what you actually want to achieve. If you can elaborate we can probably better help with suggestions.

Comment: What will be the use of this list of integers ?

Answer (score -1):

Storing random numbers in a database for comparison sounds to me like a bad idea.. Instead, try to start with something like :

```
    Random random = new Random(System.nanoTime());
    random.nextInt();
```